# Which int conforms to CKRecordValue?

Tags: cloudkit

I need to store **`int`** in `CloudKit`, but it seems neither Int 16, 32, 64 bit are supported. How do you treat this issue? I want to assign a `Core Data` value to a `CloudKit` record's  attribute.

```
recordS.setObject(recordValue, forKey:attributeName)

@property (nonatomic) int32_t recordValue; <- declaration in Core Data header
```

[image]

Comment: Show us your relevant code.  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319350.  See also http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int32_t` needs to be wrapped into `NSNumber`

```
NSNumber(int: recordValue)
```

Comment: Can you make this post (and/or your original post) a little more acceptable to a wider audience by giving more context (and code)?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> The following classes adopt this protocol and are supported by
> CloudKit:
>
> NSString
>
> NSNumber
>
> NSArray
>
> NSDate
>
> NSData
>
> CKReference
>
> CKAsset
>
> CLLocation

So your CKRecord just can't pass directly an Int from CloudKit, it needs to pass a NSNumber like so:

```
record["my_integer_key"] = NSNumber(value: my_record_value)
```

Conversely, when you want to read a CKRecord fetched from CloudKit, you can't assume it's an Int out from the box, because it's a NSNumber really :

```
my_integer_property = (record["my_integer_key"] as NSNumber).intValue
```